# Cant change date.timezone of Apache server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I followed these instructions https://cmanios.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/change-timezone-to-apache-server-and-php/ and others solution on stackoverflow but still didnt work. I checked the default time zone on PHPInfo() it's still Europe/Berlin, tried restarted Apache, even reinstall XAMPP, it's still didnt works :( Anyone had solved the same problem?

Comment: What is the Timezone you want to switch to?

Comment: Why don't you use date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok"); in PHP ?

Comment: @Samay yeah it works that way but im still confused why i cant set default value for timezone, since i find set default timezone is more convenient.
date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore"

Comment: @Poiz it's Asia/Singapore, i placed it on php.ini like this and rs apache but nothing happend.
[Date]
date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore"

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of PHP? In other words, are you sure you re editing the correct php.ini File? Naturally, it should work without problems.... if you changed the it in the right file...

Comment: @Poiz yeah i'm pretty sure it's a correct file
https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/15152454_979164838893957_1700330087_o.png?oh=b7b6296603cbf6daabd570dd0b89da17&oe=583408E5

Comment: Strange! Perhaps you could search the php.ini File to see if you have Duplicate Entries for `date.timezone=`.... sometimes, things like that happen....

Comment: @Poiz i did try that but there's just 1 file php.ini so...urghhh kind of annoying :( thanks anw :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be updating the right php.ini file.

Use this code and figure out if PHP actually uses a php.ini file or not.. and if yes which file does it use.

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be changed in the php.ini. open xampp/php/php.ini. Look for the line 'date.timezone=Europe/Berlin' and change to your timezone. in my case i changed to 'date.timezone=Africa/Nairobi'. save and restart apache. make sure you pick the right file, not php.INI-DEVELOPMENT or php.INI-PRODUCTION